# Measure limit, proof without Radon-Nikodym theorem

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\nu$ Borel measure such that $\nu(A) > 0 \Rightarrow \mu(A) > 0$. Show that limit
>   $$g(x) := \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{\nu\left(B(x,\varepsilon)\right)}{\mu\left(B(x,\varepsilon)\right)} $$ exists almost everywhere and for every Borel set $A$
>   $$\nu(A)=\int_{A}g(x)dx.$$

I've find this question at problem set for preperation for calculus exam with an adnotation **to not use Radon-Nikodym theorem in proof**. I don't know how to start with this problem so any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that integral meant to end in a $d\mu$?

Comment: is $\nu$ finite?

Comment: @IsaacSolomon I think so, user710587 there is no such assumption.

Comment: @user710587 I have rethink your question. Condition $\mu(A)>0 \Rightarrow \nu(A)>0$ pretends to be absolute continuity of $\mu$ but to fullfill ac we need $\nu < \infty$, too. So let's suppose that $\nu$ is finite.